# img tags wrapped inside li tags behaving differently in a flex box

Tags: html, css

hello i am facing difficulties in understanding the working of li items in a flex box.

it is my understanding that all the elements in a flex box become spread in a row wise fashion in their container by default... but the img tags wrapped inside li items behave differently.. when i wrap li and img items in a div and make it into on of the elements in a flexbox with flex basis 50 percent then instead of spreading in a row the li items stack on top of one another.. why is that can anyone explain ...

```css
.container .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 13px 5%;
}

.left-sidebar {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 70px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background: green;
}

.imp-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #626262;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="left-sidebar">


    <div class="imp-links">
      <a href="#"> <img src="images/news.png"> latest news </a>
      <a href="#"> <img src="images/friends.png"> friends </a>
      <a href="#"> <img src="images/group.png"> group </a>
      <a href="#"> <img src="images/marketplace.png"> marketplace </a>
      <a href="#"> <img src="images/watch.png"> watch </a>
      <a href="#"> see more </a>
    </div>


  </div>
```

left-sidebar is already a flex container. imp links is one of the elements inside.. and when i make imp links as a flex container the li items containing images are stacked on top of each other instead of in a row ... please explain

Comment: where is your CSS ?

Comment: thanks.. major correction..img are wrapped inside a tags 
.container 
.container {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 13px 5%;
}

.left-sidebar {
    
    flex-basis: 50%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 70px;
    align-self: flex-start; 
    background: green;
    

}
.imp-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #626262;
    width: fit-content;
}

Comment: add  css into your question

Comment: i am unable to edit code above properly. it is showing multiple errors and is not letting me proceed..

Comment: I've added a snippet for you then